# What is the correct way to initialize an interface?

Tags: c#

Mine is NOT a WEB application. This is completely C# libraries. My interface is very simple and in one separate C# Library:

```
public interface IDataRepository
{
    Task<string> GetAppSettingAsync(string name);
}
```

I am accessing this DLL in another C# Library.

```
public class BaseConsumer
{
    public IDataRepository DataRepository => new DataRepository();

    public async Task<string> AppSetting()
    {
       return await DataRepository.GetAppSettingAsync("name");
    }
}
```

In web/windows app, we do dependency injection and inject repository/service via the constructor. Here I don't have that choice as my libraries have parameterless constructors.

How can I get `IDataRepository` instead of initializing it using new `DataRepository`?

Comment: You can still inject it into `BaseConsumer`

Comment: You cant create instance of Interface

Comment: An interface is basically a contract that describes properties and/or methods that an object agrees to implement. You still have to create some class that implements the interface, and then you can inject into it.

Comment: Hmmm....is your `DataRepository` property returning a new instance each time?

Comment: If you have param less ctor, you're telling the calling code you have no dependencies. If you do have hidden dependencies and you're `new`ing it up, you're tightly coupling your code which defeats the purpose of DI. You should decide what approach you want to follow, you can't have both.

Comment: @JohanP injecting into baseconsumer creates another problem. BaseConsumer is inherited by more than 15 classes

Comment: @Chatra 15 classes aren't that many. Each inheriting class should get `IDataRepository` injected in ctor and then you can do `base(dataRepo)`

Comment: @JohanP few of those classes need empty constructor

Comment: @Chatra those classes that need empty ctors, do they also need use `IDataRepository`

Comment: @JohanP Yes, They need IDataRepository

Comment: @Chatra Then those classes need to get it injected too. It's kind of like `async` code, it will have to go up all the way.

Comment: Can't you write `baseConsumer.DataRepository = xxx` ?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't follow the normal DI pattern. But if other solutions fail this might help. You can just use your DI to do the binding:

```
MyDIFramework.Bind<IDataRepository>().To<DataRepository>();
```

If you are using Autofac, it will look like:

```
builder.RegisterType<DataRepository>().As<IDataRepository>();
```

Then you can resolve it when needed:

```
var dataRepository = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IDataRepository>();
```

This way you can stay parameterless.

Comment: So in .Net if you are using say Autofac, then there has to be a class where do all the DI registrations. What DI framework are you using? If you are using Autofac, search for ContainerBuilder.

Comment: As of now, no DI framework in the code. That is what I am trying to implement. This is all C# libraries and am a Web developer. so, this is new to me.

Comment: Ok. I normally use Autofac. This gives you an idea how to configure Autofac: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/implement-dependency-injection-using-autofac-ioc-container/

Comment: I'd caution about "resolve it when needed".  This is a service locator pattern and an anti-pattern when used this way. It's not really any better off than simply new-ing up concrete classes when needed, it would merely facilitate dependency substitution through the container registration. To set up unit tests you'd need to provide the container with the whole gambit of mocks to cover anything that may possibly be  "located" from within the code under test.

Comment: True, but some big project I have seen people resort o passing the container with some mocks. His situation could be calling for this.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with legacy code that doesn't conform to dependency injection, an option to consider is a service locator pattern like above. The variation that I employ I refer to as a lazy property injection:

Using Autofac I wrap the container in a Singleton for easy access.

Then in the service classes requiring the dependencies:

```
private IDataRepository _dataRepository = null;    
public IDataRepository DataRepository 
{
    get { return _dataRepository ?? (_dataRepository = ContainerRegistry.Instance.Resolve<IDataRepository>());}
    set { _dataRepository = value; }
}
```

The benefits of this approach are that dependencies are only resolved if they are needed, and only the first time they are needed. It is also a very simple validation check to ensure that the service locator is not used anywhere it isn't supposed to be. `ContainerRegistry.Resolve` should only ever be found in these Getters, so if you see it used anywhere else, talk to that dev to avoid propagating its use in places where it will be difficult to test. The pattern is fully test-able for unit testing by instantiating your class under test and providing mocks via the public setter. (Again, you only have to provide mocks for dependencies the test is expected to trigger.) For test code you can set up the container registry to throw on a Resolve call via registering an intercept as part of the fixture setup.

Comment: where to setup ContainerRegistry in C# Library ?

Comment: A common library that is referenced by any library you want to leverage dependency injection. I've added the implementation I've used for legacy apps up on GitHub: https://github.com/StevePy/Isle.IoC

I favoured the lazy property pattern previously, but now I stick to just Autofac since it supports Lazy<T> dependencies which was the one preference I had for the pattern. It's still very relevant for introducing IoC/DI to legacy applications though.